# Excel formula for summing columns based on a variable

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have created the below spreadsheet to track outstanding bills for clients.

[image: Sample spreadsheet]

I am trying to create a formula that will sum all the clients who have "No" for the value in the Paid column so I can know exactly what is outstanding at any given moment. I'm certain this can be done, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to sum the totals (column B) when Paid="No" (column F), the formula you would use in J3 for "Total Outstanding Bills" is

```
=SUMIF(F2:F13,"No",B2:B13)
```

Comment: I believe you need the = operator before NO =SUMIF(F2:F13,"=No",B2:B13)

Comment: @BradPatton I tested this before I posted it, it worked fine as is.

Answer (score 0):

Use named ranges. Select `B` column and name it `Total`. Then select `F` column and name it `Paid`. Then the formula you are looking for would be `=SUMIF(Paid,"=No",Total)`